# Regular Expression validation for custom string

Tags: java, ios, regex, flutter

**Objective**

To identify the Branded QR label to allow QR linking on app

**Description**

When a QR is scanned, the system needs to identify the format for the QR code. We are using identifiers in the code like WA000000AA. The code will be structured in the following manner.

Character 1 - W denotes Brand Name

Character 2 - A denotes Order series 1, giving 26 combinations from A to Z

Characters 3 to 8 will give flexibility of six digits so that it can go from 000001 to 999999

Characters 9 & 10 will be alphabetical from AA, AB, AC, AD, AE to ZZ. This will give 26x26 = 676 combinations.

I need to validate the string with a regex pattern. I tried a lot in [Link](https://regexr.com/) but I did not really figure how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try the following regex pattern:

```regex
^W[A-Z](?!000000)[0-9]{6}[A-Z]{2}$
```

This meets your requirements as described above.  Of note, the pattern uses `[0-9]{6}` to allows for any six digit number between `000000` and `999999`, inclusive on both ends.  But, since you want to start counting at `000001`, I added the negative lookahead `(?!000000)` to exclude `000000` from being a possible match.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Tim ... In my custom string the 1st Character is fixed which denotes "W"

Comment: I wasn't sure if there could be other letters corresponding to different brand names.

Comment: Can we allow both upper cases and lower cases for the same? @Tim

Comment: Use either `(?i)^W[A-Z](?!000000)[0-9]{6}[A-Z]{2}$` or else change the character classes to admit lowercase letters: `^[Ww][A-Za-z](?!000000)[0-9]{6}[A-Za-z]{2}$`